# Binding Button action to close an App in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have created a window with an exit button in place. In my controller.h, I have created an action like this.

```
-(IBAction) exitApp : (NSButton*) sender;
```

What should I write in the corresponding controller.m, so that the application terminates when I click the 'Exit' button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your only objective is to terminate the application, you don’t need a custom action for that. Simply hook your button to the `terminate:` action in your Application object in Interface Builder.

If you do need that custom `exitApp:` action, you can define it like this:

```
- (IBAction)exitApp:(NSButton*)sender {
    // custom termination code
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't even have to write an action method for this purpose. The "File's Owner" of the main nib is the `NSApplication` instance representing the running application itself, and it has a method `terminate:` which terminates the app.

So, just connect your button to the `terminate:` method of "File's Owner". You can see that the "Quit" entry of the menu bar provided by the Interface builder is connected to the same method of the same target.

If you really insists, implement

```
-(IBAction)exitApp:(NSButton*)sender {
   [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];
}
```

Finally, note that an application is **not** made to **exit**, but that an application is made to **quit**. So, on your button, don't put the label **Exit**... this is a Windows-ism. Instead, use the verb **Quit**. The verb **terminate** in the method selector is a NextStep-ism remaining in the Cocoa terminology, but you shouldn't use it in the visible parts of your app.

Another thing is that you can implement the delegate method

```
-(BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication
{
     return YES;
}
```

so that the app automatically quits when the last window is closed, and then you can do away with the quit button. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW9).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the explanation! I'll make sure I'll use the verb Quit now. In this case, does quitting the app terminate the app completely (as in me pressing cmd+w) or simply close it?

Comment: Well, if you implement that delegate `appli...Closed:`, the app automatically quit itself when the last window is closed. But beware the rumor that starting Lion, there's no user visible distinction between non-running applications and running applications without any open window...

Comment: You can put that rumor to rest. I'm on Mavericks now and had to implement this function to have the application terminate after the last window as closed. Thanks for the info. Was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
-(IBAction) exitApp:(id)sender {
  [NSApp terminate: nil];
}
```